# Receiving error, 'timesUsrPlayed" is not defined Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable)'

Tags: python

I defined the 'timesUsrPlayed' variable outside of the funcion so it does not reset it.  When I add 1 to the variable I get yellow wiggle lines under the times I call the var 'timesUsrPlayed' in the function 'randomPartOfGame'. when i hover over the lines it says '"timesUsrPlayed" is not defined Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable)'. I really hope I said that clearly:

```
import os
import random

# a funcion to clear the console
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

# counts the plays
timesUsrPlayed = 0

def randomPartOfGame():    
    n = random.randint(0,6)
    p = random.randint(0,6)
    print(str(n) + " and " + str(p))

    if n != p:
        print("im sorry try again")
        randomPartOfGame()
        timesUsrPlayed += 1
    elif n == p:
        print("yay you did, it took you "+ str(timesUsrPlayed) +" times to get a double")
    


def mainGameFunction():
    print('game starting...')
    time.sleep(2)
    clear()
    print('welcome you need to get a double in dice (is means get the same number)')
    randomPartOfGame()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change your code, add `global timesUsrPlayed` first of your `recursion` function *(for more details that why you need `global` variables in the `recursion` function read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341993/global-variables-in-recursion-python))*.

Then `print(f"{n} and {p}")` and `print(f"yay you did, it took you {timesUsrPlayed} times to get a double")`.

Try this:

```
import os
import random
import time


# a funcion to clear the console
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

# counts the plays
timesUsrPlayed = 0

def randomPartOfGame():    
    global timesUsrPlayed
    n = random.randint(0,6)
    p = random.randint(0,6)
    print(f"{n} and {p}")

    if n != p:
        print("im sorry try again")
        randomPartOfGame()
        timesUsrPlayed += 1
    elif n == p:
        print(f"yay you did, it took you {timesUsrPlayed} times to get a double")
    


def mainGameFunction():
    print('game starting...')
    time.sleep(2)
    clear()
    print('welcome you need to get a double in dice (is means get the same number)')
    randomPartOfGame()
```

Comment: ahh thanks, i also realized that i had the adding part after i recalled 'randomPartOfGame' so it was restarting before it added.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use global keyword before timesUsrPlayed to access the global scope variable that's what you are missing example

```
  if n != p:
        global timesUsrPlayed
         print("im sorry try again")
         randomPartOfGame()
         timesUsrPlayed += 1

    elif n == p:
   print("yay you did, it took you "+ str(timesUsrPlayed) +" times to get a double")
```